# How do I make Atom use the desired highlighting for Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I recently switched to Atom as my text editor and I'm mostly happy with it. One irritation is that I'm coding in Ruby on Rails and it chooses the wrong highlighting much of the time.

Atom (at least, my mostly-default installation) has two ruby modules: `language-ruby` v0.72.16 and `language-ruby-on-rails` v0.25.3. When I open a `.rb` or `.erb` file, it always chooses the ruby highlighting and not the rails highlighting.

*The ruby highlighting, using `HTML (Ruby - ERB)`*:

[image: Ruby highlighting]
<sub>(source: [wearefutureproofs.com](https://www.wearefutureproofs.com/images/ruby_highlighting.png))</sub>

*The rails highlighting, using `HTML (Rails)`*:

[image: Rails highlighting]
<sub>(source: [wearefutureproofs.com](https://www.wearefutureproofs.com/images/rails_highlighting.png))</sub>

I prefer the Rails highlighting but am having no luck getting it to be the default.

I've tried disabling the Ruby module, but that just makes the Rails module use the Ruby colouring when I select it, which is very odd to me. Similarly, disabling the Rails module means that my preferred highlighting isn't available (which is, to be fair, what I'd expect).

Any suggestions for how to make Atom use the Rails highlighting by default on all files when I open them?

MacOS 10.14.5, Atom 1.38.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found the [file-types](https://github.com/execjosh/atom-file-types) plugin, which over-rides the built-in system and let me force these files to load with the 'right' highlighting. My config file now looks like this:

```
  "file-types":
    "*.html.erb": "text.html.ruby"
    "*.rb": "source.ruby.rails"
```

I had to replace the existing config with those last two lines - the automatic config had some other lines but they didn't work (see @ChrisSlade's comment below). It all works properly now!

Comment: Just including the `"*.html.erb": "text.html.ruby"` and the `"*.rb": "source.ruby.rails"` lines under `"file-types":` is sufficient. I accidentally included the `"*":` under the files types and put those two lines inside the *, which doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisSlade - I've updated my answer in line with that.

Answer (score 0):

The `language-ruby-on-rails` package provides several grammars, including *HTML (Rails)* (`text.html.ruby`) and *Ruby on Rails* (`source.ruby.rails`). If you want the latter to be used for all ERB files, you can edit your Atom Config to include the following:

```
core:
  customFileTypes:
    "source.ruby.rails": [
      "*.erb"
    ]
```

The config can be edited from the Atom menu or at `~/.atom/config.cson` .Keep in mind that CSON (CoffeeScript Object Notation), like Ruby, is indentation-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks but that hasn't made any difference. (I'd tried something similar before but didn't have the details to hand so didn't mention it.) I added this to my `config.cson` file:
`customFileTypes:
  "source.ruby.rails": [
    "*.rb"
  ]
  "text.html.ruby": [
    "*.erb"
  ]` (sorry, can't get the indentation right in a comment!) but the files still open with the same highlighting they did before. :-/